# How to get DocDbWrapperScript.js?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

The Azure DocumentDB .NET (and Node.JS) code samples contain the following comment above sprocs and UDFs:

```
// Register DocDB JavaScript server API for intelisense: 
//   either add the file to Tools->Options->Text Editor->JavaScript->Intellisense->References and reference the group registered 
//   or provide path to the file explicitly.
/// <reference group="Generic" />
/// <reference path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\JavaScript\References\DocDbWrapperScript.js" />
```

**I do not know where to get that DocDbWrapperScript.js though.** Google only returns 5 pages, and those are all auto generated docs from "DocDbWrapperScript.js" on Microsoft's site.

I checked the Node.Js SDK source, did not find it there. If anyone knows where to find this, I would really appreciate that secret!

Comment: Sorry for the miss - just uploaded the file to one of our Github repositories :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the DocDbWrapperScript.js on the DocumentDB JS Github here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/blob/master/utils/DocDbWrapperScript.js

Answer (score 0):

The file appears to have moved to the following location.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/blob/master/utils/DocDbWrapperScript.js